# Drop rownames/colnames/names without explicitly setting those to NULL in R

Tags: r

Given this data:

```
data <- read.table(text="
   age married house income gender class
1   22       0     0     28      1     0
2   46       0     1     32      0     0
3   24       1     1     24      1     0
4   23       0     1     40      0     1
5   50       1     1     28      0     1
")
```

Whenever I take a section of more than one value I also get the row and/or col names,
e.g.:

```
> data[1, 1:2]
  age married
1  22       0
```

Is there some way to drop any names and make this nameless (no labels) without explicitly setting anything to NULL beforehand (or loading in a file with `row.names=F` etc.)?

The goal is just to be certain nothing is attached when something like nameless(..) is called.

```
# Not OK 
colnames(data) <- NULL
data[1, 1:2]

# OK
nameless(data[1, 1:2])
[1] 22 0
```

Example:

```
output
[[1]]
       income                      
     4     36      2      3     NA 

[[2]]
    age             
  1  48   4   5  NA
```

Comment: The previous answer posted did solve my problem though, so for now I am assuming that only column names are  going to show up when passing the value?

Comment: Just out of curiosity; in which scenario would you need something like this? Why/when is it a problem when column names are attached?

Comment: When you add this value to a list it will show up with a column name above it, while other items in that list might have completely unrelated other names attached.

Comment: The reason I was hesitant to add an example is that people might say: "But you can just use print/format if you are concerned how it will show up on screen".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unlist()` has a `use.names` argument that will drop the names.

```
unlist(data[1, 1:2], use.names = FALSE)
```

Or if everything being returned is of the same type you can use e.g. `as.integer()` on it:

```
as.integer(data[1, 1:2])
```

Comment: The `unlist` way does seem to be the intended way here.

Comment: Fastest, and only one function.

Answer (score 3):

Looks a bit silly, but what about:

```
unname(unlist(data[1, 1:2]))
#[1] 22 0
```

Comment: Doesn't win a beauty contest indeed, I am hoping for a neater way. Otherwise,  I will accept this answer, +1.

Comment: It is also slower than the other proposed methods.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing `unname` from @alexwhan

```
unname(c(data1[1,1:2]))
[1] 22  0
```

Comment: This and the `unlist(.., FALSE)` take the same speed.